# Slideshow in four directions

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slideshow

Just a quick question here; Is there a slideshow that scrolls right, left, up and down? The idea is to showcase the different projects when scrolling up and down and the different images within each project when scrolling left and right. Would that be possible? Most importantly, would that be possible?

Thanks all,

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://hakim.se/experiments/css/slideshow/#/) out, it is a CSS 3D slideshow made by Akhim that should get your interest.

Comment: Thanks man!! That could be what I'm looking for! It'll require a lot of tweaking to get what I want but it's definitely down that route.